# subclassing a UITableViewCell with UIImageView in it

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have subclassed a `UITableViewCell` and inside I have a `UIImageView`, the problem is that when I tap on the `UIImageView`, I wanted to do something, but what happens now is that it calls the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. How do I prevent this? Also, should I just add a tap gesture recognizer to the `UIImageView` to perform some action I want?

Comment: Normally, the `userInteractionEnabled` is NO in UIImageView. Did you set it to YES?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a `UIButton` with your image instead of a `UIImageView`? `UIButton` has all the `UIControl` functionality.

I'm trying to remember if that's enough to avoid `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and I don't remember though I think it is. Do you still want the row to be selectable by tapping outside the image? If not, you can just return `NO` to `canSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: the issue is that whenever I click on the button/image it dismisses the cell that I am it, and therefore the view is gone.. I don't want this to happen

Comment: Did you make it a button? And when you say "dismisses", do you mean calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`? You need to make sure the image accepts the touch (which making it a UIButton should do) and make sure it doesn't pass the touch event up the responder chain, which I believe the button should also do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes simply add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the `UIImageView` is the way to go.

Don't forget to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on your `UIImageView` too.

Then, when you will tap on your `UIImageView`, the touch event will be captured by its `UITapGestureRecognizer` and won't be transmitted to the cell, so the method associated with your `UITapGestureRecognizer` will be called but the `tableView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` delegate method won't. *(This latter delegate method will only be called if the touch event is not captured by a subview of your cell before)*